# Star Delegate in QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I have copied stardelegate, stareditor and starrating source and header files from example http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-stardelegate-example.html, and i try to implement star rating functionality into a tree widget instead of a table widget like from example. The stars are showing, the problem is that are not editable like in the aforementioned example, in fact the whole row. My code causing this:

```
ui->tree->setItemDelegate(new StarDelegate);
ui->tree->setItemDelegateForColumn(2, new StarDelegate);
ui->tree->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::DoubleClicked | QAbstractItemView::SelectedClicked);
ui->tree->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
ui->tree->setColumnCount(3);
ui->tree->setHeaderLabels(QStringList() << "Name" << "Date" << "Rating");
```

Please tell me what i am doing wrong, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QTableWidget` items are editable by default, `QTreeWidget` items are not.

You will have to add the flag `Qt::ItemIsEditable` to the existing flags for all the items in the rating columns.